# Помогите определить тропы/фигуры речи

Tags: стилистика, тропы, фигуры-речи

Никак не могу разобраться какие тропы/фигуры содержат выделенные части предложений.

> 1. *Итак, Одесса для тех, кто ее **не знает** и **не хочет знать**. Довольно красивый город **на нашем Юге и чьем-то Севере**. На берегу
>      Черного моря, трехтысячный юбилей которого мы недавно отмечали
>      (Жванецкий).*

Касательно этого примера у меня даже нет никаких предположений...вот не знаю и все.

> 2. ***Большое количество*** бросило меня, **кое-кого** бросил я, о чем жалею (Жванецкий).

Здесь пропущено слово...*"большое количество **людей***" - может **эллипсис**? А может **антитеза**: *"большое количество"* противопоставляется *"кое-кому"*?

Вот информация о тропах и фигурах

- [Тропы_средства выразительности | lingvist.ucoz.ru](http://lingvist.ucoz.ru/forum/19-37-1)
- [5.2. Риторические фигуры | studfiles.ru](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/6018979/page:19/#36)

Comment: Во втором примере речь идет об Амфитезе:  приём описания целого путём указания на крайние точки:
От Москвы до самых до окраин,
***С южных гор до ***северных морей*** (Лебедев-Кумач).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Итак, Одесса для тех, кто ее **не знает и не хочет знать.** - градация по признаку повышения нежелания знать.
   Довольно красивый город **на нашем Юге и чьем-то Севере**.- обычная антитеза Юг-Север, наш(российский)-чей-то(для живущих на юге иностранцев).

На берегу Черного моря, трехтысячный юбилей которого мы недавно отмечали - у Вас не отмечено, но это тоже фигура - парцелляция

2. **Большое количество** бросило меня, **кое-кого** бросил я, о чем жалею -антитеза, если нужно определить особенности выделенного.

Comment: Это же в прежние времена написано, когда Одесса была "нашей"? Нет, значит, имелось в виду для украинцев и иностранцев-южан

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что в этих примерах использован **парадокс** (неожиданное, странное высказывание, которое внешне противоречит здравому смыслу), с помощью таких высказываний создается комический эффект.

1) Автор собирается рассказать об Одессе тем, **кто ничего не хочет знать** об этом городе.

2) **Сложно бросить (покинуть) друг друга**, обычно покинутой бывает одна сторона.

3) На нашем Юге и чьем-то Севере. Это похоже **на каламбур или оксюморон:** эти приемы основаны на выходе слов за рамки обычных понятий, на совмещение несовместимого. Название "наш Юг" условно, для кого-то это север.

Comment: Не вижу парадокса, по-моему, всё очень здраво:для кого-то это юг, а для кого-то север, его бросили много женщин, кого-то бросил он - вполне житейская ситуация. Оксюморон - это "живой труп"или "грустный смех",а здесь всё совместимо

Comment: Это же ЖВАНЕЦКИЙ, поэтому речь идет о приемах и средствах создания  КОМИЧЕСКОГО.  К примеру, что-то рассказывается для тех, кто не знает, и это понятно, но тут же добавляется - и не хочет знать, и это вызывает улыбку: оказывается, рассказ рассчитан на тех и других. Можно, конечно, увидеть градацию, антитезу, но не они вызовут смех в зале. Здесь нужно нечто неожиданное, ведь юмор основан на несоответствии ожидаемого и реального.  Мне кажется, что задание именно на эту тему: отыскать приемы комического.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно согласна, что искать надо не тропы и изобразительно - выразительные средства, а способы выражения комического. Но раз речь зашла о фигурах и тропах...
 Итак, Одесса для тех, кто ее не знает и не хочет знать. Довольно красивый город на нашем Юге и чьем-то Севере...  По - моему,в обороте "не знает и не хочет знать" используется лексический повтор форм слова "знает - знать". А в выражении "на нашем Юге и чьем-то Севере..." присутствует двойная антитеза "наш - чей - то", "Юг - Север" и вполне допустимая ирония.

Comment: Что подразумевается под способами выражения комического?

Comment: Я думаю, что кроме ИВС - формального выражения юмора, существует ещё и содержательный юмор, выражающийся в семантической наполненности, может быть, в лексической (со) или (несо)четаемости, в определённом отборе материала, в теме и идее... Не могу всего перечислить, не сильна в терминологии. А ИВС - это только форма, способ подачи.